# How to compare changes of monthly values in different years in a dataframe, Pandas/Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe where columns are

```
'Jan-2001' 'Feb-2001' ... 'Dec-2001'... 'Jan-2002' ... 'Dec-2002' ... 'Jan-2018' ... 'Dec-2018'.

  200        190.4          55.23         12.3            130.2        30                42 

  ...
```

The values of these columns are float numbers. I need to find the change in a value for the same month in a different year. For example, I need to check how much the value has changed in March-2018 from the previous year, March-2017 and so on for other months/years. I need to mark all of the values that have changed for 30% from a previous year. For example, if a value in April 2018 has changed for 30% comparing to April 2017 value, I need to mark it. How do I search values by the same months but different years in a dataframe is my biggest problem.

What I did is transposed a dataframe, so now I have dates instead of columns in rows (date is a dataframe index now), I have assigned new columns 'month' and 'date' to a dataframe, but not sure how to approach this and if that is the way to go. Grouping with aggregation is not an option I guess because my values will change if I take sum/mean for example and I can't change them.

UPDATE:

Transposed dataframe:

```
Jan-1990    200     1.2    .... 45
Feb-2001    190.4   287.5  ...  2.1
 ...
```

Comment: It is recommended to provide a sample dataset in text format

Comment: As @Yuca said you should have a look at [mcve](/help/mcve)

Comment: Everything is explained, don't know what else could I add. Added one row of data for your convenience.

Comment: it's not about being explained, is about providing a sample data set so we can test and confirm the desired output. Adding sample data makes it easier for people to give you answer, but if  you don't want to listen to our suggestions then it's ok, we're just trying to help

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use the [built-in python date format](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/datetime.html).
First you should parse your strings to this date format, most likely using [strptime](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime).

Then you can define a timedelta of 1 year, and add or subtract this to the current date. 
This will allow you to search for the same date in your pandas dataframe (pandas natively supports indexing on datetimes or date periods.
Instead of manually using timedelta's, you can probably also use a [pandas.date_range](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.date_range.html) with a period of 1 year.

Comment: I don't see how will this allow me to know that the value in February-2005 has changed for a certain amount in February-2006? Dates are different - months are the same but years are different.

Comment: It should allow you to easily select all datapoints that happened in february for all the years (by using a good range). On this subset of the dataframe, you can then apply a diff to get the yearly increase for that month. Then it's just a matter of filtering for the thresholds that you determined. Unless I'm misunderstanding what you want to achieve?

Comment: No, I think you understood correctly, just a bit confused with the date_range but will try it out.

Comment: Do you have a code example perhaps? I am not sure how to proceed. Do I keep my dataframe in the original format or in a transposed format? I updated my question.